# Swift JSONSerialization as NSDictionary can't get to values inside

Tags: ios, json, swift

[JSON Results from output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqmQo.png) This image should help I am trying to get to [9] "vehicleLocation"

I have an API from UTA that tracks transit data in real-time and displays JSON data

```
     let url = URL(string: "UTA API")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            AlertController.showAlert(_inViewController: self, title: "Error", message: ("Fatal Error"))
        } else {
            if let urlContent = data {
                do {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                    print(jsonResult)
                    //get to item within dictionary
                    let speed = jsonResult["speed"] as? [String:Any]
                    print(speed)
                } catch {
                    AlertController.showAlert(_inViewController: self, title: "Error", message: "JSON Processing Failed")
                }
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

this returns JSON data:

```
{
    "serviceDelivery": {
    "vehicleMonitoringDelivery": {
      "vehicleActivity": [
        {
          "monitoredVehicleJourney": {
            "extensions": {
              "lastGPSFix": "2017-11-27T23:58:28.083",
              "speed": 5.8690799999999994
            },
```

I want the speed value and display in a label. But it comes up nil.
 Any ideas and help would be welcomed.
 Thanks

Comment: Why are you allowing fragments when you expect a dictionary? Why are you handling exceptions, and at the same time tell your app to crash when it doesn't receive a dictionary? Doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: So if allowing fragments is not the way to go. Would it be better to do mutableContainers? This specifies that arrays and dictionaries are mutable objects.  Allowing fragments allows top lvl objects not part of NSArray or NSDictionary.   And to answer why.  That is why I am asking questions, because I do not understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrVehicleActivity = jsonResult["serviceDelivery"]?["vehicleMonitoringDelivery"]?["vehicleActivity"] as? [Any]
for i in 0..<arrVehicleActivity?.count {
    var strSpeed = arrVehicleActivity?[i]?["monitoredVehicleJourney"]?["extensions"]?["speed"] as? String
    print("Output should be speed :\(strSpeed)")
}
```

Hope will helpful to you!!

> print("Output should be speed :(strSpeed)")
>
> Output should be speed : 5.8690799999999994

Comment: @ Tubelight when I use   var arrVehicleActivity = jsonResult["serviceDelivery"]?["vehicleMonitoringDelivery"]?["vehicleActivity"] as? [Any] it comes back with type 'Any' has no subscript members

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to access value with key `speed` at the first level, but it's actually way lower in the hierarchy, beyond a lot of children.

Answer (score 0):

first try to access high level objects then when you reach speed cast it as string not as dictionary this will get you the value

```
let jsonString = "{\"device\":\"iPhone 6\",\"OS\":\"iOS 9\",\"name\":\"Apple\"}"
let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String : Any]

print (json!["name"] as! String)
```

Comment: Why `.mutableContainers`? You are assigning the result to an immutable constant.

Comment: sorry my mistake edited now i just write code in hurry to clarify my point

Answer (score 0):

```
let dic = value[keyPath: "serviceDelivery.vehicleMonitoringDelivery"]
let array = dic["vehicleActivity"] as? NSArray
for speedValueDic in array{
 let speed = speedValueDic["speed"] as? String
 print(speed)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment I get an ambiguous reference to member 'value(forKey:)' when i use the let dic = value[keyPath: "]